# How do I use 'F' keys in gtk Accelerators?

Tags: python, gtk, accelerator

I'm trying (in python) to use gtk.Widget.add_accelerator... what should I pass as  accel_key to use the F keys? Have attempted to check the docs to no avail.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `gtk.accelerator_parse()`. [Here is an informative post on dealing with keyboard codes in pygtk](http://www.islascruz.org/html/index.php?Blog/SingleView/id/Pygtk%3A-About-keyboard-accelerators).

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
key,mods=gtk.accelerator_parse("F10")
```